# Is condition number important when fitting splines?

Tags: splines, condition-number

I am fitting data using p-splines. The authors of p-splines, Eilers and Marx, remark that there is no technical requirement to have a small number of knots and in fact you can have many more knots than data points without worry. However, I notice that the matrix I'm inverting has an extreme condition number when the number of knots is large. Is this a problem?